# warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'search_form'

Tags: theming, debugging

I am getting a warning when I use a new theme, I've got error that *search form not found*.

> warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'search_form' not found or invalid function name in /......./...../includes/form.inc on line 377.
>
> Line 377
> $form = call_user_func_array(isset($callback) ? $callback : $form_id, $args);

I have tried changing some items on line 377.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either

1. Enable the core search module or
2. remove the search form block from being rendered in your theme (perhaps in template.php or page.tpl.php)